# How to offset text without offsetting background-img

Tags: html, text, offset

I wish to offset text from its' current position so the margin is 20 px in from the left side.  I have tried putting everything after "from students" in a table, as follows:    and that just removed all the text altogether.

In essence, I have a thin image about 200 px wide and 1000 px tall.  I need this text to be indented about 20 px so it doesn't look so sloppy.  Any ideas?

Let me know if I'm missing any criteria.

```
<div class="right" style="background-image: url(/images/gala_r3_c2.jpg); height: 1000px; width: 225px;  position: relative; ">  
    <h1>FROM STUDENTS</h1>
    <br>
    <i>CONTENT HERE</i>
    <br><br>
    <div id="topmenu"><b><a href="thanks.html"> &#62; FOR MORE</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: ]Give the div a 20px padding](http://jsfiddle.net/LyskW/)?

Comment: Adding padding-right:15px; worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a 20px padding to the left of your containing div:

```
<div class="right" 
 style="padding-left:20px; 
  background-image: url(/images/gala_r3_c2.jpg);
  height: 1000px;
  width: 225px;
  position: relative; ">
```

You might want to adjust padding around the the other sides of the div in the same way to improve appearance.

Incidentally, is there a specific reason why the styling is in-line and not in a style sheet?

Comment: I have had some issues coding and linking to a style sheet.  It works sometimes and doesn't other times.

Also, that code seemed to just take the image and move it over 20px, not the text itself.
http://newhope.edu/index.php/static/Gala

Comment: I got it figured out, see above comment.  I'll give you credit since you helped, and added answer.  Thanks!

Comment: No matter how much `padding-bottom` I give my element, it doesn't push the content up. The padding area is sitting on top of the contents according to inspect element.

Answer (score -1):

I think Using background image is not good solution.
We can make that using 'text-shadow' property.
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-shadow/
Thanks